# Getting UUID for a particular bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I am using the below snippet to get the UUID for the devices that are in the range. Now i need to get only UUID's(services) for the devices that i select. How should i pass the name of the bluetooth device so that i get services for that device only.

```
if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID.equals(action)) 
{
BluetoothDevice device =intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
Parcelable[] uuidExtra = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
for (int i = 0; i < uuidExtra.length; i++) {
String abc=uuidExtra[i].toString());
}
}
else if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID.equals(action)){
            Iterator<BluetoothDevice> itr = mDeviceList.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                // Get Services for paired devices
                BluetoothDevice device = itr.next();
                showToast("\nGetting Services for " + device.getName() + ", " + device);
                if(!device.fetchUuidsWithSdp()) {
                    showToast("\nSDP Failed for " + device.getName());
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you referring to Ble when you say you want to fetch services?

Comment: no i haven't used any GATT attributes or BLE to fetch services. This is the basic Bluetooth code. I have no problem in using BLE codes but i don't know whether that will discover only ble devices like led lights or also normal devices like mobiles. @7383